# What is the correct way to create a NativeScript Angular component that supports a tap event?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Suppose the following simple template:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-component',
    template: '<Label text="Test me"></Label>'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

How can I add support for usage like this:

```
<test-component (tap)="onTap($event)"></test-component>
```

## I have tried:

#### Adding a tap event and wrapping the component template in a `StackLayout`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-component',
    template: '<StackLayout (tap)="passTap(e)"><Label text="Test me"></Label></StackLayout>'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() public tap = new EventEmitter();
    pressTap(event: any) {
        this.tap.emit(event);
    }
}
```

But this has weird results, sometimes emitting the event twice and seems inconsistent across iOS and Android. It also feels very clunky.

#### Registering my element as various things that support tap, like `StackLayout` or, I was hoping, `LayoutBase`:

```
import { registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";

registerElement('test-component', () => LayoutBase);
```

I also tried making my Angular component extend `LayoutBase` etc., and then tried to map `this.on("tap", ...)` but nothing happened.

Is there a correct way to support this? Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Comment: What you have tried seems to be the right way. If you are facing issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: @Manoj which bits are correct? registerElement to LayoutBase, then extend LayoutBase in my component and map `on("tap", ..)` - or have my own tap EventEmitter in a wrapper element?

Comment: Emitting tap event is correct.

Comment: With the wrapper element in my component HTML or from extending LayoutBase and binding `on("tap", ..)`? Sorry I'm still not sure as both ways involve emitting a tap event :)

Comment: Also is `LayoutBase` the best choice to call `registerElement` with, or `ViewBase` or `View`? I can't find a good NS article on it

Comment: But `registerElement` is used for NS component not Angular component like above one.

Comment: emitting event is the correct way. I am using this for many of my conponents and it always work fine on both android and ios.